# Getting "contract validate error : Owner no asset!" when create a NFT

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, tron

I trying to create a NFT in a contract on Tron blockchain, my function is this:

```
async function createNFT()  {
        let contract = await tronWeb.contract().at('address of contract'); 
        let result = await contract.mintWithTokenURI("my wallet", id, "urlToNFT").send({
            feeLimit:100_000_000,
            callValue:0,
            tokenId:1000036,
            tokenValue:100,
            shouldPollResponse:true
        });
}
```

but I always get this error:
[error printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPy1y.png)

```
error: "CONTRACT_VALIDATE_ERROR", message: "contract validate error : Owner no asset!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first provide a key in method `send` that represents your address.

```js
... .send({
from: myPublicAddress,
...
})
```

This trick should solve your problem, otherwise I guss your contract implements ownable interface, so just the owner can mint tokens.